# Find a WCF service caller's Active Directory domain username

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-security

Consider a WCF service using `WsHttpBinding` for which only the domain users are allowed to call this service.

How can you find the Active Directory username of the caller?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Get the value of `System.ServiceModel.ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity.Name` property.

It does not matter which binding you use as long as the security mode is different from `None` for the binding.

If the security mode is `None` then `System.ServiceModel.ServiceSecurityContext.Current` will be `null`.

Comment: "It does not matter which binding you use" - I don't think that's correct. For me the `Name` property was only populated with `Windows` authentication mode.

Answer (score 9):

You can get identity of the user by calling:

```
ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity.Name
```

or

```
OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.WindowsIdentity.Name
```

Answer (score -4):

You will have to add some sort of User information to the message structure you are using to contact the service.

e.g.

```
public class UserInformation
{
  public string User { get; set; }
  public string Password { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Request
{
  [DataMember]
  public UserInformation User { get; set; }
  [DataMember]
  public MyRequest RequestBody { get; set; }
}
```

This way you can query active directory at your client side, populate the UserInformation object and send over the user details as part of the message structure.